# Display/Hide PartialView in main page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, razor-pages, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm using ASP.NET MVC framework. Here I'm loading PartialView from a main.cshtml. PartialView contains a modal which supposes to show when the user clicks a link. Following functionality works correctly, but as I'm loading the PartialView at the beginning of main.cshtml page it always displays on the top. I want a portion of PartialView contains `headerCommentModal` should display and it should only display after the user clicks the link. How can I achieve this?

---

This how I'm calling PartialView from main.cshtml

```
@Html.Action("SubmissionHeader", "Submission", new { id = 516, tab = 0 })
```

---

This is my link and `DisplayCommentDialog` function which is loading `headerCommentModal` from PartialView and displaying when the user clicks the below link.

Link: `<a href='DisplayCommentDialog' onclick="DisplayCommentDialog(); return false;"> Add Comment</a><br>`

```
function DisplayCommentDialog() {
    $('#headerCommentModal').modal({
        show: true,
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
      });
}
```

---

Here is my action

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult SubmissionHeader(int? id, SubmissionTabEnum tab = SubmissionTabEnum.None)
        {
          var rules = DIResolver.GetConcreteInstanceOf<ISubmissionRules>();
            var model = _submissionSvc.GetSubmissionHeaderViewModel(id.GetValueOrDefault()) ?? new SubmissionHeaderViewModel();

            ................


            TempData["SubmissionHeaderID"] = id;
            return PartialView("_SubmissionHeader", model);
        }
```

---

And lastly here is my partial view.

```
        <script>
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        })
    </script>
    
    @{
        int SubmissionHeaderID = (int)TempData["SubmissionHeaderID"];
        bool isClosed = Model.SubmissionStatusTypeID == SubmissionStatusEnum.Close.GetEnumValue();
    }
    
    @Html.Hidden("SubmissionHeaderID", SubmissionHeaderID, new { data_ng_model = "model.SubmissionHeaderID" })
    
    @Html.JsonDataSourceVariable("securitygroupsusers", "SecurityGroupsUsersAccessRight", "Utility", Model.EntityOrganizationID.GetValueOrDefault())
    
    <!-- _SubmissionHeaderActions  start  -->
    <div class="stayenabledonclose" id="_SubmissionHeaderActions">
        @* not a CSS class - signal to JS code that this should still be enabled when submission closed *@
        @*Note: row is shared with _SubmissionHeader, so col-md value has to fit with it*@
        <div class="col-md-4" ng-controller="submissionHeaderActionsController">
    
            <div class="btn-group pull-right" style="margin-top:10px;padding-top:10px;">
    
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="color:white;background-color:rgb(16,123,147);font-size:16px;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Action Items
                    <b class="caret" style="display: inline-block"></b>
                    <div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    @if (UC.SecurityModel.EntityOrganizationAccessRight(Model.EntityOrganizationID.GetValueOrDefault()) == AccessRightEnum.ModifySubmissions)
                    {
                        if (Model.CanCreateNew)
                        {
                            <li><a value="New Submission" class="stayenabledonclose valid" ng-click="showCreationModal($event)" aria-invalid="false">New Submission</a></li>
                        }
                        if (Model.CanTransfer)
                        {
                            <li> <a value="Transfer" class="dropdown-item  stayenabledonclose" ng-click="transfer($event, 358)">Transfer</a> </li>
                        }
                        if (Model.CanClone)
                        {
                            <li><a value="Clone" class="dropdown-item stayenabledonclose" ng-click="clone($event)">Clone</a></li>
                        }
                        @*if (Model.CanEditComments)
                            {
                                <li><a value="Comments" class="dropdown-item   stayenabledonclose" id="comment-btn" ng-click="showCommentModal($event)" >Comments</a></li>
                            }*@
                        @*if (Model.CanReassign && !isClosed)
                            {
                                <li><a value="Reassign" class="dropdown-item   stayenabledonclose" id="reassign-btn" ng-click="showReassignModal($event)" >Reassign</a></li>
                            }*@
                        if (Model.CanExport)
                        {
                            <li><a ng-click="export($event)" href="@Url.Action("SubmissionHeaderActionItem", "Submission", new {id = SubmissionHeaderID, item = (int) SubmissionActionItemEnum.Export})" title='Exports submission & attachments to a zip file.'>Export</a></li>
                            
                        }
                        if (Model.CanPrint)
                        {
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("SubmissionHeaderActionItem", "Submission", new {id = SubmissionHeaderID, item = (int) SubmissionActionItemEnum.Print})" title='Exports submission to a PDF file.'>Print</a></li>}
                        if ((Model.ArchiveStatusTypeID == 2 || Model.ArchiveStatusTypeID == 3) && Model.CanGetArchive)
                        {
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("SubmissionHeaderActionItem", "Submission", new {id = SubmissionHeaderID, item = (int) SubmissionActionItemEnum.GetArchive})" title='Retrieves submission archive file.'>Get Archive</a></li>}
    
                        if (Model.ArchiveStatusTypeID == 3 && Model.CanDeleteArchive && UC.SecurityModel.EntityOrganizationAccessRight(Model.EntityOrganizationID.GetValueOrDefault()) == AccessRightEnum.ModifySubmissions)
                        {
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("SubmissionHeaderActionItem", "Submission", new {id = SubmissionHeaderID, item = (int) SubmissionActionItemEnum.DeleteArchive})" title='Deletes submission archive file.'>Delete Archive</a></li>}
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top:20px;">
                @if (Model.CanEditComments)
                {
                    <div class="circle-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Comments" style="float:right;margin-right:20px;">
                        <div class="circle-text"><a value="Comments" class="stayenabledonclose" id="comment-btn" ng-click="showCommentModal($event)">C</a></div>
                    </div>
                }
    
                @if (Model.CanReassign && !isClosed)
                {
                    <div class="circle-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Reassign" style="float:right;margin-right:20px;">
                        <div class="circle-text"><a value="Reassign" class="stayenabledonclose" id="reassign-btn" ng-click="showReassignModal($event)">R</a></div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="submissionHeaderActionsController">
            <div id="headerCommentModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="submissionComment-title" style="padding-right:19px;">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div id="adcmodal" class="modal-content">
                        <div id="adcmodal" class="modal-header col-nopadding ">
                            <h3 class="modal-title" id="submissionComment-title">Submission Comment</h3>
                            <button type="button" class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body submissioncomment-modal-body">
                            <div class="row form-group spacer">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.Label("Recipients")
                                        <select id="commentrecipients" class="dirtyignore" kendo-multi-select k-options="securitygroupsusersSelectOptions()" k-ng-model="initSecurityGroupsUsers()"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            @Html.Hidden("SubmissionHeaderID", SubmissionHeaderID)
                            <div class="row form-group spacer">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @Html.Label("Comment (will be sent to the recipients via email)")
                                        @Html.TextArea("Comment", "", new { @class = "form-control dirtyignore", rows = "2", maxlength = "1000", data_ng_model = "model.comment" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="adcmodal" class="modal-footer ">
                            <input type="button" id="Close" value="Close" class="adcmodal-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" />
                            <input type="button" id="Send" value="Send" class="adcmodal-button" ng-click="send(@Model.EntityOrganizationID)" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        @if (Model.SubmissionID != 0)
        {
            @Html.SubmissionReassignmentActions(Model.SubmissionID) @* Submission.SubmissionReassignment  _SubmissionReassignment*@
        }
    
        @Html.SubmissionCreationActions()  @*  Submission.CreateNewSubmission  _SubmissionCreation  *@
    
        @Html.SubmissionTransferActions(Model.SubmissionID)  @*  Submission.TransferSubmission  _SubmissionTransfer  *@
    
    </div>
    <!-- _SubmissionHeaderActions  end  -->
    
    @using (Html.RequiredScripts())
    {
        @Html.RequirePageScript("Shared", "SubmissionHeaderActions")
    }
```

---

This is my main.cshtml where actually dialog show with partialview modal. Here I've  @Html.Action and also DisplayCommentDialog function body.

```
    @*@if (ViewBag.ShowSsoOptinMessage)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function ($) {
                var fun = document.querySelector('universal-navigator');

                if (fun) {
                    fun.maybeDisplayOptInView(true);
                }
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    }*@

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="test_template">
    <div id="details-container">
        <p>Testing...</p>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="details"></div>


<div ng-controller="submissionDashboardController">

    @Html.JsonDataSourceVariable("customfieldmaps", "CustomFieldMaps", "Utility")

    <script>
                var includeClosed = @Model;
                var preventAllGridDataLoad = true;
                var preventMyGridDataLoad = true;
    </script>

    <!---- ListSubmissionDashboard start  -->
    <!-- bread crumb content -->


    @Html.Action("SubmissionHeader", "Submission", new { id = 516, tab = 0 })
    <div class="spacer-bodybg"></div>


    <!-- _SubmissionCreation start -->
    @Html.SubmissionCreationActions()  @* SubmissionController.CreateNewSubmission  returns view _SubmissionCreation  which is modal  *@
    <!-- _SubmissionCreation end -->
    <!---- ListSubmissionDashboard end  -->

    <div id="dialog"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dialog").kendoWindow({
                modal: true,
                visible: false,
                modal: true,
                visible: false,
                resizable: false,
                width: 450,
                height: 420,
            });

            var detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());

        });

        function showDetails(e) {
            var grid = $("#mysubmissionsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            $(grid.tbody).on("click", "td", function (e) {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
                var colIdx = $("td", row).index(this);
                //alert(rowIdx + '-' + rowIdx);

                var result;

                if (rowIdx != null) {
                    dataRow = grid.dataItem(grid.tbody.find("tr").eq(rowIdx));
                    var entityOrganization = dataRow.EntityOrganization;
                    var SubmissionCode = dataRow.SubmissionCode;
                    var kendoWindow = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");

                    var content = "<h7><b>" + "Last Comment Created by </b> " + user.toString() + "</h7><br>" +

                        "<h7>" + "" + "<a href='DisplayCommentDialog' onclick=\"DisplayCommentDialog(); return false;\">" + "Add Comment" + "</a><br></h7>" +

                        "</div><br>";

                    kendoWindow.content(content.toString());
                    kendoWindow.open().toFront();
                }
            });

        }

                        });

        var kendoWindow = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
        kendoWindow.open().center().toFront();
                    }

        function DisplayCommentDialog() {

            var kendoWindow = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
            kendoWindow.close();
            alert('Before calling headerCommentModal');

            $('#headerCommentModal').modal({
                show: true,
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            });
        }


    </script>


    @using (Html.RequiredScripts())
    {
        @Html.RequirePageScript("Shared", "ShortcutLinks")
        @Html.RequirePageScript("Submission", "ListSubmissionDashboard")
        @Html.RequirePageScript("Shared", "GridPersonalization")
        @Html.RequirePageScript("Shared", "SubmissionCreation")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this.
If I understand the subject correctly. As follows:

Create an action on your controller that you can call partial.

```
public ActionResult SubmissionHeader(int id = 516,int tab = 0)
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Next step Add jQuery to your project and call the action with it

```
$("#headerCommentModal").modal("hide");
$("#DisplayCommentDialog").click(function(){
    $.get("/Controller/SubmissionHeader?id=516&tab=0",function(result){  
     $("#headerCommentModal").modal("show");
     $("#headerCommentModal").html(result); 
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. This is not exactly working. I've already have an action and I've also added added the full partial view and the main.cshtml. Do I need to modify anything in order to fit your suggested code. $("#headerCommentModal").modal("show"); doesn't show at all.

Comment: I also tried to get the exact div to hide. It actually hides with this following code but when I try to show headerCommentModal after clicking it also switches off. If I don't hide it with this following code show up before and also on click. What could be the issue? $("div.row.submission-header-title").css("display", "none");

Comment: Checking if you got a chance to check this issue? I tried few other approaches, I noticed unless I hardcode this code, @Html.Action("SubmissionHeader", "Submission", new { id = 516, tab = 0 }) -- partial view "headerCommentModal" does not show up at all when I click on the link.  Any idea what could be a possible alternative? Would be helpful if you could throw some lights.